# Apache Ignite becomes unresponsive on bad exit of client node

Tags: java, caching, ignite

We have Ignite cluster having server(data/cache) and client(worker) nodes where client pulls data from server nodes to perform computation. This setup works fine except sometime this whole cluster becomes unresponsive and we have to restart the complete grid. The pattern I observe is:

1. Any of the client(worker) node exit the cluster/topology w/o publishing Node exit event.
2. This triggers following exception on data nodes.

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Timeout was reached before computation completed.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7563) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:260) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:172) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:141) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3229) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3013) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2960) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2100) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendOrderedMessage(GridIoManager.java:2365) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1964) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1935) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1917) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendNotification(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1324) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.addNotification(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1261) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler.onEntryUpdate(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:1059) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler.access$600(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:90) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler$2.onEntryUpdated(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:459) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryManager.onEntryUpdated(CacheContinuousQueryManager.java:447) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:2495) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2657) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2118) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1935) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1734) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.processNearAtomicUpdateRequest(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:3322) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$400(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:141) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:273) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:268) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1142) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:591) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:392) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:318) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:109) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:308) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1907) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1528) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5300(GridIoManager.java:241) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.execute(GridIoManager.java:1421) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:55) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.body(StripedExecutor.java:565) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Timeout was reached before computation completed.
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.handleUnreachableNodeException(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3304) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3211) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.access$6700(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:307) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$CommunicationWorker.processDisconnect(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:5150) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$CommunicationWorker.body(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:4951) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi$5.body(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2503) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:58) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    Suppressed: org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.internal.NodeUnreachableException: Failed to connect to all addresses of node 46ea1c96-edbb-4c92-ae15-4930b48c6d84: [/10.228.29.168:47000]; inverse connection will be requested.
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3982) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3635) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3375) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3180) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteFutureTimeoutCheckedException: Timeout was reached before computation completed.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:244) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:160) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:152) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.handleUnreachableNodeException(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3301) [ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    ... 7 common frames omitted
```

3. I can see following warning on server node which could be related:

```
Possible starvation in striped pool.
    Thread name: sys-stripe-5-#6%pv-ib-valuation%
    Queue: [Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFilterRequest [filter=[o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheEntrySerializablePredicate@35b24146], parent=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateRequest [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=775, val=null, hasValBytes=true], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractSingleUpdateRequest [nodeId=null, futId=786433, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateRequest [res=null, flags=needRes]]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFilterRequest [filter=[o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheEntrySerializablePredicate@77901da5], parent=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateRequest [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=775, val=null, hasValBytes=true], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractSingleUpdateRequest [nodeId=null, futId=835585, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateRequest [res=null, flags=needRes]]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=fae5b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, miniId=0be5b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988830, order=1663551612761, nodeOrder=674], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], subjId=f3e89bcb-caa0-4004-bc24-dc7bbf2687ed, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateFilterRequest [filter=[o.a.i.i.processors.cache.CacheEntrySerializablePredicate@5d7d3932], parent=GridNearAtomicSingleUpdateRequest [key=KeyCacheObjectImpl [part=775, val=null, hasValBytes=true], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractSingleUpdateRequest [nodeId=null, futId=802817, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], parent=GridNearAtomicAbstractUpdateRequest [res=null, flags=needRes]]]]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=bbb6b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, miniId=cbb6b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988830, order=1663551612762, nodeOrder=674], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], subjId=f3e89bcb-caa0-4004-bc24-dc7bbf2687ed, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=dbb6b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, miniId=ebb6b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988830, order=1663551612763, nodeOrder=674], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], subjId=f3e89bcb-caa0-4004-bc24-dc7bbf2687ed, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=fbb6b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, miniId=0cb6b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988830, order=1663551612764, nodeOrder=674], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], subjId=f3e89bcb-caa0-4004-bc24-dc7bbf2687ed, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=1cb6b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, miniId=2cb6b635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988830, order=1663551612765, nodeOrder=674], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], subjId=f3e89bcb-caa0-4004-bc24-dc7bbf2687ed, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=464b9635381-7057249e-b58b-42aa-ac97-d99f8f02bb68, miniId=564b9635381-7057249e-b58b-42aa-ac97-d99f8f02bb68, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988830, order=1663551612460, nodeOrder=673], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], subjId=276a2bbe-45a2-473e-bdea-31c41e87a7a9, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=664b9635381-7057249e-b58b-42aa-ac97-d99f8f02bb68, miniId=764b9635381-7057249e-b58b-42aa-ac97-d99f8f02bb68, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988830, order=1663551612461, nodeOrder=673], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=716, minorTopVer=0], subjId=276a2bbe-45a2-473e-bdea-31c41e87a7a9, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=8693c635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, miniId=9693c635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988857, order=1663551612767, nodeOrder=674], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=743, minorTopVer=0], subjId=f3e89bcb-caa0-4004-bc24-dc7bbf2687ed, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]], Message closure [msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridNearGetRequest [futId=7693c635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, miniId=a693c635381-3bb423f1-d4d5-4223-90d4-e239b7254f34, ver=GridCacheVersion [topVer=274988857, order=1663551612766, nodeOrder=674], keyMap=null, flags=5, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=743, minorTopVer=0], subjId=f3e89bcb-caa0-4004-bc24-dc7bbf2687ed, taskNameHash=0, createTtl=43200000, accessTtl=-1, txLbl=null, mvccSnapshot=null]]]]
    Deadlock: false
    Completed: 432169
Thread [name="sys-stripe-5-#6%pv-ib-valuation%", id=41, state=TIMED_WAITING, blockCnt=24514, waitCnt=284215]
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at o.a.i.i.util.IgniteUtils.sleep(IgniteUtils.java:7894)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1991)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1935)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendWithRetries(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1917)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.sendNotification(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1324)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.continuous.GridContinuousProcessor.addNotification(GridContinuousProcessor.java:1261)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler.onEntryUpdate(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:1059)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler.access$600(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:90)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryHandler$2.onEntryUpdated(CacheContinuousQueryHandler.java:459)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.query.continuous.CacheContinuousQueryManager.onEntryUpdated(CacheContinuousQueryManager.java:447)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry.innerUpdate(GridCacheMapEntry.java:2495)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateSingle(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2657)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.update(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:2118)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1935)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1734)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.processNearAtomicUpdateRequest(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:3322)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.access$400(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:141)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:273)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$5.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:268)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.processMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:1142)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:591)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:392)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:318)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:109)
        at o.a.i.i.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:308)
        at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1907)
        at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1528)
        at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$5300(GridIoManager.java:241)
        at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.execute(GridIoManager.java:1421)
        at o.a.i.i.managers.communication.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:55)
        at o.a.i.i.util.StripedExecutor$Stripe.body(StripedExecutor.java:565)
        at o.a.i.i.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

4. Grid graually started to slow down and at the end it just become unresponsive.

Any lead what could be wrong with it and why client exit is causing data/server node to become unresponsive?

**Continuous Query From Worker/Client:**

```
IgniteCache<String, Object[]> cache = ignite.cache("dataCache");
ContinuousQuery<String, Object[]> query = new ContinuousQuery();
CacheEntryUpdatedListenerAsync<String, Object[]> listener = e -> e.forEach(this::processCacheEvent);
query.setLocalListener(listener);
cache.query(query);
```

Comment: Can you share the code you use to subscribe to Continuous Queries? I assume all clients subscribe to them?

Comment: You should increase timeout on java thin client: ClientConfiguration target = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800", "127.0.0.1:10801").setTimeout(<<time in milliseconds>>);

Comment: @DanutRadoaica  we are using thick client. Will try to that for them.

Comment: for thick client: IgniteConfiguration#setNetworkTimeout, IgniteConfiguration#setFailureDetectionTimeout, IgniteConfiguration#setClientFailureDetectionTimeout, IgniteConfiguration#getDiscoverySpi#setNetworkTimeout,IgniteConfiguration#getDiscoverySpi#setSocketWriteTimeout

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov I found code which we run from our worker node. I have added it as part of original question.

Comment: Hmm... Someone should write a test that: 
1. Starts multiple thick clients and a cache
2. Starts CQ on each
3. Writes into the cache continuously
4. Hard-kills one of the clients (`kill -9` or use some test trickery to avoid client from waving goodbye)

There might be one already in the Ignite codebase. Unfortunately, I don't have time to check right now.